# SSRS IIF Expression- IFF not Declared?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to write an IFF statement in SSRS report inside Visual Studio.

For this scenario, In my data I have the following two fields, MaxCompareDateLapse and MaxCompareDateLapse2. Both of these return integer values.  I also have a parameter which has the following values available for the use to select: 3, 6, 9, 12

I'm entering an IFF statement in an expression and I'm getting back the error **'The Value Expression for the textrun 'MaxCompareDateLapse.Paragraphs[0]' contains an error: [BC30451] 'IFF' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level'**

I've tried the following two expressions and they both give me back the same error.  The first one below is ultimately what I want to get it, and the second one I simplified a bit to see if it would work but I still get the error.

Code #1

```
=IFF(Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value < 
Parameters!pMonthsNoActivity.Value, Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse2.Value, 
IFF(Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value >= 
Parameters!pMonthsNoActivity.Value, Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value))
```

Code #2

```
=IFF(Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value < 
Parameters!pMonthsNoActivity.Value, 
Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse2.Value, 
Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value)
```

So for example 1.  If MaxCompareDateLapse =1, Parameter = 6, and MaxCompareDateLapse = 20, then 20 would be returned.  If MaxCompareDateLapse = 7, Parameter = 6, and MaxCompareDateLapse = 5, then 7 would be returned

Thanks in advance - still pretty new to this stuff

Comment: The correct code is : "IIF" not "IFF"

Comment: F*** me. Thanks.. solves one thing but I get a different error now - Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIF' accepts this number of arguments.  Is there really too many arguments here? I may have to submit this separately

Comment: What is your error now?

Comment: I got it fixed and working. I ended up using =IIF(Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value < Parameters!pMonthsNoActivity.Value, Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse2.Value, Fields!MaxCompareDateLapse.Value) and it gave me the results I wanted.  Thanks for the follow up - really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the IFF with IIF as that is the correct syntax.

Refer to foll. example:

```
    =IIF( Expression to evaluate,
what-to-do when the expression is true,
what-to-do when the expression is false )
```

You can nest using the 2nd and/or 3rd arguments based on your requirements. Example if you want to nest another IIF check if the above expression is false:

```
 =IIF( 1st Expression to evaluate,
what-to-do when the 1st expression is true, 
IIF( Another Expression (2nd) to evaluate,what-to-do when that 2nd expression is true,what-to-do when that 2nd expression is false ) 
)
```

Hope this helps.